# UPDATE query for 180k rows in 10M row table unexpectedly slow

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a table that is getting too big and I want to reduce it's size
with an UPDATE query. Some of the data in this table is redundant, and
I should be able to reclaim a lot of space by setting the redundant
"cells" to NULL. However, my UPDATE queries are taking excessive
amounts of time to complete.

Table details

```
-- table1  10M rows (estimated)
--         45 columns
--         Table size 2200 MB
--         Toast Table size 17 GB
--         Indexes Size 1500 MB
-- **columns in query**
--   id     integer      primary key
--   testid integer      foreign key
--   band   integer
--   date   timestamptz  indexed
--   data1  real[]
--   data2  real[]
--   data3  real[]
```

This was my first attempt at an update query. I broke it up into some
temporary tables just to get the id's to update. Further, to reduce the
query, I selected a date range for June 2020

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE A as
    SELECT testid
      FROM table1
     WHERE date BETWEEN '2020-06-01' AND '2020-07-01'
       AND band = 3;
 
CREATE TEMP TABLE B as    -- this table has 180k rows
    SELECT id
      FROM table1
     WHERE date BETWEEN '2020-06-01' AND '2020-07-01'
       AND testid in (SELECT testid FROM A)
       AND band > 1
       
UPDATE table1
   SET data1 = Null, data2 = Null, data3 = Null
 WHERE id in (SELECT id FROM B)
```

Queries for creating TEMP tables execute in under 1 sec. I ran the UPDATE query for an hour(!) before I finally killed it. Only 180k
rows needed to be updated. It doesn't seem like it should take that much
time to update that many rows. Temp table B identifies exactly which
rows to update.

Here is the EXPLAIN from the above UPDATE query. One of the odd features of this explain is that it shows 4.88M rows, but there are only 180k rows to update.

```
Update on table1  (cost=3212.43..4829.11 rows=4881014 width=309)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=3212.43..4829.11 rows=4881014 width=309)
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=3212.00..3214.00 rows=200 width=10)
              ->  Seq Scan on b  (cost=0.00..2730.20 rows=192720 width=10)
        ->  Index Scan using table1_pkey on table1  (cost=0.43..8.07 rows=1 width=303)
              Index Cond: (id = b.id)
```

Another  way to run this query is in one shot:

```
WITH t as (
    SELECT id from table1
     WHERE testid in (
        SELECT testid
          from table1
         WHERE date BETWEEN '2020-06-01' AND '2020-07-01'
           AND band = 3
        )
    )
UPDATE table1 a
   SET data1 = Null, data2 = Null, data3 = Null
  FROM t
 WHERE a.id = t.id
```

I only ran this one for about 10 minutes before I killed it. It feels like I should be able to run this query in much less time if I just knew the tricks. This query has EXPLAIN below. This explain shows 195k rows which is more expected, but cost is much higher @ 1.3M to 1.7M

```
Update on testlog a  (cost=1337986.60..1740312.98 rows=195364 width=331)
  CTE t
    ->  Hash Join  (cost=8834.60..435297.00 rows=195364 width=4)
          Hash Cond: (testlog.testid = testlog_1.testid)
          ->  Seq Scan on testlog  (cost=0.00..389801.27 rows=9762027 width=8)
          ->  Hash  (cost=8832.62..8832.62 rows=158 width=4)"
                ->  HashAggregate  (cost=8831.04..8832.62 rows=158 width=4)
                      ->  Index Scan using amptest_testlog_date_idx on testlog testlog_1  (cost=0.43..8820.18 rows=4346 width=4)
                            Index Cond: ((date >= '2020-06-01 00:00:00-07'::timestamp with time zone) AND (date <= '2020-07-01 00:00:00-07'::timestamp with time zone))
                            Filter: (band = 3)
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=902689.61..1305015.99 rows=195364 width=331)
        Hash Cond: (t.id = a.id)
        ->  CTE Scan on t  (cost=0.00..3907.28 rows=195364 width=32)
        ->  Hash  (cost=389801.27..389801.27 rows=9762027 width=303)
              ->  Seq Scan on testlog a  (cost=0.00..389801.27 rows=9762027 width=303)
```

**Edit**: one of the suggestions in the accepted answer was to drop any indexes before the update and then add them back later. This is what I went with, *with a twist*: I needed another table to hold indexed data from the dropped indexes to make the A and B queries faster:

```
CREATE TABLE tempid AS
    SELECT id, testid, band, date
      FROM table1
```

I made indexes on this table for id, testid, and date. Then I replaced `table1` in the A and B queries with `tempid`. It still went slower than I would have liked, but it did get the job done.

Comment: instead of `where id in (select id from B)`, try `where exists (select 1 from B where B.id = table1.id)`.  It might make a difference.  Also, be sure to index `id` in table `B`

Comment: Please show us the `EXPLAIN` execution plan for the query.

Comment: @jjanes, EXPLAIN plans added for both versions of UPDATE query.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. You're right. It's time to update. I was ignoring this database because it was working just fine. But now I can see it's time to give it some love.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have another table that has a foreign key to this table to one or more columns you are setting to NULL. And this foreign table does not have an index on the column.

Each time you set the row value to NULL the database has to check the foreign table - maybe it has a row that references the value you are removing.

If this is the case you should be able to speed it up by adding an index on this remote table.

For example if you have a table like this:

```
create table table2 (
  id serial primary key,
  band integer references table1(data1)
)
```

Then you can create an index `create index table2_band_nnull_idx on table2(band) where band is not null`.

But you suggested that all columns you are setting to NULL have array type. This means that it is unlikely that they are referenced. Still it is worth checking.

---

Another possibility is that you have a trigger on the table that works slowly.

---

Another possibility is that you have a lot of indexes on the table. Each index has to be updated for each row you update and it can use only a single processor core.

Sometimes it is faster to drop all indexes, do the bulk update and then recreate them all back. Creating indexes can use multiple cores - one core per index.

---

Another possibility is that your query is waiting for some other query to finish and release its locks. You should check with:

```
select now()-query_start, * from pg_stat_activity where state<>'idle' order by 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm wondering what to look for in that last query. Most of the returned data does not look especially useful, except for maybe the `waiting` column.  There are no triggers for this table and the updated columns are not foreign keys. The updated columns ARE arrays and I suspect they account for much (maybe nearly all) of the Toast Table size. I'll give it a shot to drop the indexes

Comment: If I'm dropping indexes (indices), do I also need to drop the primary key?

Comment: In pg_stat_activity you just look for long running transactions - they will be on the bottom of results thanks to order. You should leave the pk so the db can find the rows to delete by id.